# Python has 42 builtin functions whereas documentation list 68

Tags: python

Python has 42 builtin functions,

however, official documentation lists 68 built-in Functions.[2. Built-in Functions — Python 3.6.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

It is easy to get just 42 built-in functions:

```
builtins_dict = {}
for i in all_builtins:
    if type(eval(i)) not in builtin_dict:
        builtin_dict[type(eval(i))] = 1
    else:
        builtin_dict[type(eval(i))] += 1
```

output:

```
{<class 'type'>: 92, 
<class 'ellipsis'>: 1, 
<class 'bool'>: 3, 
<class 'NoneType'>: 4, 
<class 'NotImplementedType'>: 1, 
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>: 42, 
<class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'>: 1, 
<class 'str'>: 1, 
<class '_sitebuiltins._Printer'>: 3, 
<class '_sitebuiltins.Quitter'>: 2, 
<class '_sitebuiltins._Helper'>: 1}
```

It is easier to categorize all the builtins by 'type'

What's the logic underlying?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm delighted that you will be volunteering to help with Python documentation in the future.  Of course you are professional.

Comment: *Python has 42 builtin functions, however ... 68* – what?

Comment: Rather than discussing whole lists of functions, do you have a specific concern about one particular function we can discuss?

Comment: I edited follow your segguestion, why they downvote for unknown? @AzatIbrakov

Comment: get it. however, a good structure in mind about all the functions can really helps.

Comment: You are failing to count various built-ins that are called exactly like functions (`int()` and `str()`, for example), but are actually implemented as types.

Comment: get it. however, a good structure in mind can really helps and worth of discussing.@JohnZwinck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects listed under Built-in Functions in the docs aren't there because of their type. They're there because they're callable, and they do something deemed interesting enough to document when you call them. From a duck-typing perspective, they're functions.

Many of them are types, such as `int` and `super`.